# How can I study the convergence of the following series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac {n(-1)^n}{3n -1} $?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

How can I study the convergence of the following series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac {n(-1)^n}{3n -1} $?

**My trial:**
I thought about the alternating series as I found that $a_{n}$ is decreasing but lim $a_{n}$ for me was equal to 1/3 not zero, so the test fails .... Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a_n = \dfrac{n(-1)^n}{3n-1};$

$\lim_{n \rightarrow }a_n \not =0$.

Hence?

Comment: Does not any absolutely convergent series is convergent?

Comment: hopefully. Every abs. convergent.  series is convergent. Not every convergent series is abs. convergent: altern. harm. series: (\sum (-1)^n/n converges , the harmonic series does not.

Comment: so what is the value of the limit of $ a_n $ in our case?

Comment: hopefully.a_n is not convergent. Subsequence a_{2n} goes to +1/3.Subsequence a_{2n+1} goes to -1/3.So what can you say about the sum?

Answer (score 2):

It's just that: $a_n$ = $n(-1)^n/(3n-1)$ does not go to zero, so the series could not converge.

Comment: Does not any absolutely convergent series is convergent?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Any series that converges must have it's sequence going to zero, that's the very first fact about infinite series that you should know.